# Transforming an outcome/dependent variable in predictive modeling

Tags: machine-learning, pca, predictive-models, data-transformation, caret

The distribution of the outcome variable in my predictive model has data points that are constructed in the following way: `x = a^2 + b^2 + c^2`.

[image: the distribution]

As I'm reading *Applied Predictive Modeling* I get the feeling that I have to transform this outcome variable to get a better model without predicting *a*, *b* and *c* separately. Using a Box-Cox transform doesn't help me unfortunately. Any suggestions?

```
caret::BoxCoxTrans(df$outcome.var)

## Lambda could not be estimated; no transformation is applied
```

Comment: Can you show the results of `str(df$outcome.var)`?

Comment: @topepo `num [1:5544] 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 9 ...` is what that gives me. `outcome.var` ranges from 0-75.

Comment: Try using a Yeo-Johnson transformation. Box-Cox only works for positive data and you have zeros.